# Mod operator in java for negative number is not working?

Tags: java, modulo

In Java I had tried

```
-1 % 20
```

expecting it to return -1... but the actual value is 19.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: No, it really isn't. It's -1: `int x = -1; int y = x % 20; System.out.println(y);` prints -1. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Instead appears you tried -1+20 = 19

Comment: Will take care of same next time.. @JonSkeet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a positive result, you can wrap the mod.

```java
public static int PositiveMod(int value, int mod)
{
    return ((value % mod + mod) % mod);
}

int result = PositiveMod(-1, 20); //Returns 19
```

Comment: This is how modulo should work by default :/
Python understands just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The modulo-operation is semantically tightly bound to the integer-division since the following equation should always hold:

```
x = a * (x / a) + (x % a)
```

And since `-1 / 20` is `0` in Java, this means that `-1 % 20` shoudl be `-1` for the equation to hold. If you are talking about residue classes within the natural number, you can interpret `-1` as `19`, but a resudie class is mathematically not bound to the modulo-operator.

Answer (score 2):

`-1` isnt divisible by `20` so the result is `-1` as expected

Comment: Google calculator gives -19 when i do this calculation.

Comment: Better ask to Google.....not to StackOverflow

Comment: @LokeshSingal no matter which define of the integer division you apply (there are actually 2), `-19` is definitiely wrong. Maybe you meant `19`?

Comment: @LokeshSingal In Mathematics, values in Mod N are conventionally reduced to [0,N), including negative values. In Assembly code, and therefore most programming languages, Modulo is just the remainder from a division. This means `%` can return negative values. Technically speaking, ...-21, -1, 19, 39... Mod 20 are all the same, but not when programming.